# How do I forward packets from specific physical port in the switch to another IP address, only if that packet's destination was specific IP address?

Tags: networking, forwarding, draytek

How do I forward packets from specific physical port in the switch to another IP address, only if that packet's destination was specific IP address?

We are using Unifi SWitch and Draytek Vigor 300B Router.

Answer (score 0):

your looking for dNAT, does this router support it?

Otherwise, this can be handled by a firewall on your network(specific ip on port to be allowed)

If your looking to block a specific physical port, there are a few ways.  Take a look at this commands and see if they translate using acccess groups

(these are cisco commands, but if you have any CLI look for similar abilities)

```
ssh into switch
# config
# access-list 1 deny 192.168.13.165 
# int eth 15/22    #<--15th port
# ip access-group 1 out
# write memory
```

Comment: Thank you Michael, I think I didn't explain my logic well. The role is ( If a packet detected going to IP address 192.168.1.10 through port number 9100 using the PHYSICAL PORT IN number 15 in the switch, then forward it to another IP Address )